# test a class that uses random values

Tags: java, junit

I need to test a class that use random.nextDouble() is there elegant way to provide the test these number so to be able to foresee the executed output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend to embed random numbers generator into separate component and inject it into your class. Thus, you would be able to inject its mocked instance in tests. It's the most elegant solution in my opinion. You can also do some tricks with reflection and override random generator created within class body but this is not recommended at all.

Comment: +1: Although seeding the RNG works (@Adam's answer), IMO a mock is a cleaner solution, as it avoids the hidden state.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is: use seeded randoms.

You should add an extra package-private constructor to your class allowing that class to take a seed for its random.  In that constructor, instead of writing

```
random = new Random();
```

write

```
random = new Random(seed);
```

to initialize the private field `random`.  By [creating a Random with a seed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29), you initialize the internal state of the Random from the seed.  Since a Random isn't actually random but is a pseudorandom number generator that bases its next returned value on the current state, by setting the initial state you deterministically set the sequence of numbers returned by a series of calls to Random.

In your testing code, initialize new objects of type `Foo` using this special package-private testing constructor rather than the default constructor, and as long as you pass in the same seed every time the class you are testing will get the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers every time.

Answer (score 0):

What is your test trying to prove?  That `nextDouble` actually returns specific values?  That doesn't seem like a very useful test to me.

The best you can do in this kind of situation is to prove that if you run your code a large number of times, that you get a different random number each time.  Run it in a loop of say 1000, and store the results in some kind of `Set`.  Then assert that the size of the `Set` is the same as the number of times you've iterated the loop.

To do better than this would require that you quantify exactly what you mean by "random".  Whole books have been written on this, and it's not really a useful thing to try and do in a unit test.

Comment: Why is (acceptance) testing a probabilistic algorithms not useful?

Comment: I'm glad you asked. Part of the point of an automated test, such as JUnit gives you, is that you can run it very often, and know that if the software is working to spec, then the test will pass.  Any conditions that you put on a series of random numbers (for example, at least 40% of them must fall in each half of the allowed range) can legitimately fail - in fact, MUST occasionally fail, if the program works correctly. So there's no way to express "these numbers are random" in a JUnit test, if you want it to pass every time you run it. Of course, you can test that the numbers are generated ...

Comment: ... by a particular algorithm (such as that of `random.nextDouble`), but that can't possibly reflect the business requirements of the system; and therefore shouldn't be the thing that you're testing.  The only reasonable thing to do is to place a wrapper around a `Random`, stub the wrapper, then test that the right things are happening to the random number after it has been generated.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. What about acceptance testing a Las Vegas algorithm that always terminates? What about a randomized algorithm that may return different values, but all results must meet certain criteria?

Comment: I think that it's appropriate to use an automated JUnit test to test that a Las Vegas algorithm gives the correct result. To verify that it uses resources well, you'd be better off running it a few times and doing some kind of profiling of whatever resources you're interested in. That is to say, it's a manual ad hoc test, not an automated one - you wouldn't want to repeat it every time you run the JUnit tests in your project.  In the second case you mentioned, just have a JUnit test for whether the results meet the "certain criteria"; I don't think you should have a test of the randomisation.

Comment: And I see now that the OP didn't specifically mention that this was an automated test, or that it used JUnit.  I think I looked at the "junit" tag, then kind of read it assuming that this is what it had to be.  Maybe I should modify my answer accordingly; I definitely answered from a JUnit POV.